How do I run a SELECT query on a MySQL database in vb.net?
I've been using vb.net  (visual studio 2022) to run INSERT and DELETE queries on a MySQL server, but now I need to run a SELECT query and get the returned values.
My code to run the INSERT query looks like this:
Public Function StoreData() As Object
    'Write the times and types to the tblparams table of the database
    Dim strS1Type As String, strS2Type As String, sM1Ts As String, sM2Ts As String, sM1Tr As String, sM2Tr As String
    Dim connectionString As String, iReturn As Boolean


    'Connection String to connect with MySQL database.
    connectionString = "server=xx.xx.xx.xx;userid=user;password=password;database=database"

    Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
            With sqlCommand
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbldata(M1Type, M1Start, M1Tr, M2Type, M2Start, M2Tr, M1SheetType, M2SheetType) VALUES(@M1Type, @M1Start, @M1Tr, @M2Type, @M2Start, @M2Tr, @M1SheetType, @M2SheetType);"
                .Connection = SQLConnection
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@M1Type", strS1Type)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@M1Start", sM1Ts)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@M1Tr", sM1Tr)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@M2Type", strS2Type)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@M2Start", sM2Ts)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@M2Tr", sM2Tr)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@M1SheetType", GlobalVariables.strM1SheetType)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@M2SheetType", GlobalVariables.strM2SheetType)
            End With
            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                iReturn = True
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                iReturn = False
            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

End Function

From what I've read, having the code in the USING clauses ensures that the connections to the database are closed when it exits the USING clauses. I have tried to modify this code to return data from a SELECT query:
Public Sub RestoreData()
    'Read the start times and types from the tblparams table of the mtmdev database and load into controls
    Dim connectionString As String, iReturn As Boolean, vResult As String, i As Integer, a As Array
    'Define connection String to connect with MySQL database.
    connectionString = "server=xx.xx.xx.xx;userid=user;password=password;database=database"
    Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
            With sqlCommand
                .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbldata;"
                .Connection = SQLConnection
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            End With
            i = 0
            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                 sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
                While vResult = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader.GetValue(i)
                    MsgBox("Result is:" & vbCrLf & vResult)
                    i = i + 1
                    iReturn = True
                End While
            Catch ex As MySqlExceptionSystem
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                iReturn = False
            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub


But that results in the following error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'This MySqlConnection is already in use. See https://fl.vu/mysql-conn-reuse '
when it gets to the line:
While vResult = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader.GetValue(i)

Should I be using a different syntax to read the field values returned by the query?

Consider using a DataTable to contain your return data https://stackoverflow.com/a/10845783/741136

I'd also recommend listing your column names, rather than using SELECT *

@SSS, for the record, a DataTable is a means to store data, not to retrieve it, and whether you should use one depends on how you want to use the data. If you just want to use the data record by record as you read it then the data reader alone is appropriate. If you want to have random access to the data but not save any changes, a data reader and a DataTable can be used together. If you want to save changes, a data adapter and a DataTable together would be appropriate.

@jmcilhinney the asker is attempting to load each column in a loop. I suspect a DataTable is more in line with what they are trying to achieve. YMMV

I actually only have one row of data, so don't need a DataTable.
Also, the SELECT * was just for the purpose of getting the code working, now I'm listing the column names in the query ;-)

You are calling ExecuteReader twice, which doesn't make sense. As any example on the web would have shown you, you call ExecuteReader and it returns a data reader, then you use that to read the data, e.g.
Using connection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString),
      command As New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
    connection.Open()

    Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Console.WriteLine($"{reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Id"))} - {reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name"))}")
        End While
    End Using
End Using

Read will return True if and only if there is a row to read, so that loop will read each row in the result set.

Thanks for that answer - that and this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884500/sql-data-reader-only-reads-the-first-row-in-vb-net which explained the syntax I needed to extract the fields returned by Execute.Reader. I had done a fair bit of searching before asking this question, but there were so may answers using different structures to the one I was using for my INSERT and DELETE queries. I wanted the SELECT queries to use the same basic structure and your answer gave me exactly what I wanted!
